# Convert key, values JSON array to tabular JSON format

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have following JSON data for Chart

```
var chartJson = [
    {
        header : '2016',
        values : [1, 5, 9]
    },
    {
        header : '2017',
        values : [2, 4, 8]
    },
    {
        header : '2018',
        values : [3, 1, 5]
    }
];
```

And needs to convert it into this format to feed my HTML table

```
var tableJson = [
    {
        2016 : 1,
        2017 : 2,
        2018 : 3
    },
    {
        2016 : 5,
        2017 : 4,
        2018 : 1
    },
    {
        2016 : 9,
        2017 : 8,
        2018 : 5
    }
];
```

Any quick help will be appreciated to convert it into this format.
I tried using this code, but somehow missing on the logic.

```
let table = [];
    for(var row of chartJson ){
        for(var value of row.values)
        {
            table.push(
                {
                    column : row.header,
                    value : value
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: values are always with 3 elements?

Comment: @Yoel, I would assume not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Iterate through every `chartJson`'s element with its' values(through inner loop) till `values'` length and make an object from that.
2. Finally, push that object into the `table` array.

That's it.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
var chartJson = [
    {
        header: '2016',
        values: [1, 5, 9]
    },
    {
        header: '2017',
        values: [2, 4, 8]
    },
    {
        header: '2018',
        values: [3, 1, 5]
    }
];

let table = [];
let len_of_chartJson = chartJson.length, len_of_values = chartJson[0].values.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len_of_chartJson; i++) {
    let obj = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < len_of_values; j++) {
        obj[chartJson[j].header] = chartJson[j].values[i];
    }
    table.push(obj);
}

console.log(table);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var chartJson = [{
    header: '2016',
    values: [1, 5, 9]
  },
  {
    header: '2017',
    values: [2, 4, 8]
  },
  {
    header: '2018',
    values: [3, 1, 5]
  }
];

let table = [];
chartJson.forEach((row, index) => {
  row.values.forEach((val, j) => {
    table[j] = { ...table[j],
      [row.header]: val
    }
  });
});

console.log(table)
```

Comment: it means, keep the original json, and just add a new (key:val).

Comment: table[0] will be {2016: 1}, and for the latter forEach, table[0] would be {2016:1, 2017:2}

Answer (score 0):

```
let table = chartJson.reduce((tbl, rec) => {
          rec.values.forEach((num, index) => {
                  if(!tbl[index]){
                          tbl[index] = {}
                  }
                  tbl[index][rec.header] = num
          })
          return tbl
          }, [])
```

Array reduce function is used to loop through each object, than for each object it loop through each value, checking if the index exist in the table, if it does not exist, it create an empty object at current index. Finally it creates a key value in the current index object.

You read more about reduce function below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce